# How to hide those .exe and .o created by codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

it is kinda annoying to have all those .exe and .o lying around, but i only want to hide the .exe created by codeblocks but not other app, or set the result of the compilation to other folder, is that possible?

Comment: C::B does not stamp files in any special way that allows detecting which files were built by C::B (or programs it uses) versus something else.   Simply do a "Build/Clean" in C::B to delete them.   It is always possible to regenerate such files .... for example, if you need a copy of the executable.   There are ways to control input, output, and include paths.

Comment: The screenshot on http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-40001.2 shows an "*Objects output dir*" setting.